# Getting Repeated 403 error on WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

When htaccess file was replaced it works fine for a while, then again showing 403 error repeatedly. Writng Allow in line 3 can be done but again it keeps on changing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4x3I.jpg)

Comment: It is a requirement here that you place all required information _directly_ into the question. A reference to some external resource, be it text or an image (as you did) is _not_ a valid replacement for that. So please take the time to edit your question. Thanks.

Comment: In general: wordpress does indeed alter such a distributed configuration file. You have two options: 1. you place your directives in the actual http server's host configuration or 2. you obey the comment wordpress makes in the file it writes itself.

Comment: Where's the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment markers?